# Reflection without refraction

Tags: transparency, reflection

If you use alpha to make an object transparent, specular reflections disappear with it. Glass is a complicated shader with refraction, I only want to make an object transparent where only the specular reflections are visible, and it doesn't bother with calculating anything else, like refraction.

Answer (score 0):

Use this shader for your objects - pay attention to the Blend Mode settings on the right (if using EEVEE):

[image: RefractNO]

Comment: But that's only half transparent. What does diffuse shader have to do with specular reflections? Why not mix the Glossy shader with transparent instead of diffuse in the first place?..

Comment: @madscribbles If this answer solved your Q consider mark this A as accepted https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour to make this site organised. Thank you